# CloverETL Graph Specific

Tags: java, jsf, graph, clover

I am uploading a xls file and .grf file. But my requirement is to check the numeric field of xls file and if is there any string presents I have to replace with 0. But It must have at run time. Because there are many users and different types of xls and .grs file. How to read and write clover file at runtime? Is there any way to read excel and check string in numeric field and replace that string with 0? I am using jsf and java.

Answer (score 1):

- set the field to be of numeric type

  set default value to 0

  set dataPolicy on Reader to *controlled*

Then all invalid (string) values, will be replaced with default value.